# Transpose Excel rows if the first column has particular text

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where data exists for a single person across several rows:

e.g.

```
Name            Speed       Work Done
John Doe        10          
knob twisting               2
lever pulling               15
Jane Doe        14
knob twisting               12
Joe Doe         5
lever pulling               3
```

I want to just attribute total work done for each person so that I get something like the following:

```
Name            Total Work Done
John Doe        17
Jane Doe        12
Joe Doe         3
```

Tried transposing and splitting on values, but I haven't quite figured out what to split on exactly.

I've looked into some VBA iterating over the rows and summing up the individual total work done in the following

```
Sub Button3_Click()
  Dim jobs As Variant
  jobs = Array("knob twisting", "lever pulling")

  Dim sizeOfJobs As Integer
  sizeOfJobs = UBound(jobs) - LBound(jobs) + 1

  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ActiveSheet

  Dim totalRows As Integer
  totalRows = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count + sh.UsedRange.row - 1
  Dim userJobs() As Long
  ReDim userJobs(totalRows)

  Dim row As Range
  Dim userRow As Integer

  For Each row In sh.UsedRange.Rows
    If sh.Cells(row.row, 0) <> "Name" Then
      If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Cells(row.row, 0).Value, moves, 0)) Then
        userRow = row
      Else
        userMoves(userRow) = userMoves(userRow) + sh.Cells(row.row, 4).Value
      End If
    End If
  Next row

  Dim element As Variant
  For Each element In userMoves
    Debug.Print element
  Next element
End Sub
```

I keep getting a "Method '_Default' of object 'Range' failed" which I'm not sure what that means

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you ask a question here you should always show what you have tried so far, what research you have done, and come up with the code you have so far (because this is not a free code writing service). Otherwise your question is too broad to be answered. You can read [ask] and [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more column next to name (for e.g. Activity) and move all your activites there. To get Total you could use function Sum If.

```
Name       Activity type    Speed   Work Done
John Doe   knob twisting     10     2
John Doe   lever pulling            15
Jane Doe   knob twisting     14     12
Joe Doe    lever pulling      5     3


Total   Total work done         
John Doe        17  -> =SUMIF(A2:A5,A9,E2:E5)       
Jane Doe        12  -> =SUMIF(A2:A5,A10,E2:E5)  
Joe Doe         3   -> =SUMIF(A2:A5,A11,E2:E5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue with the code in that Cells start at 1 while arrays start at 0

```
Sub Button3_Click()
  Dim jobs As Variant

  jobs = Array("knob twisting", "lever pulling")

  Dim sizeOfJobs As Integer
  sizeOfJobs = UBound(jobs) - LBound(jobs) + 1

  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ActiveSheet

  Dim totalRows As Integer
  totalRows = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count + sh.UsedRange.row - 1
  Dim userJobs() As Long
  ReDim userJobs(totalRows)

  Dim row As Range
  Dim userRow As Integer

  For Each row In sh.UsedRange.Rows
    If sh.Cells(row.row, 1).Value <> "Name" Then
      If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Cells(row.row, 1).Value, jobs, 0)) Then
        userRow = row.row
      Else
        userJobs(userRow - 1) = userJobs(userRow - 1) + sh.Cells(row.row, 9).Value
        userJobs(row.row) = 0
      End If
    End If
  Next row

  Dim job As Variant
  Dim rowNum As Integer
  rowNum = 1
  For Each job In userJobs
    If job <> 0 Then
      sh.Cells(rowNum, 10).Value = job
    End If
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
  Next job
End Sub
```